# Automatically assigning tags in org-mode

Tags: emacs, tags, org-mode

I hate assigning tags when the tag already exists in the headline.  I'd like to figure out a way to have org-mode evaluate a headline (preferably right after I hit "enter") and, if it contains any words that match tags in my org-tag-alist, have those tags created for the headline.

As an example:

If I have various individual's names and various project names and possibly even terms like "today", "tomorrow", and "next week" already in my org-tag-alist then, when I type something like:

*"TODO Remember to ask Joe tomorrow about the due dates for the XYZ project."*
and hit enter, then the headline would be evaluated and the tags *:Joe:XYZ:Tomorrow:* would be generated for the item.

Has anyone seen something like this or have a suggestion as to how I could go about it myself?

Comment: I am only aware of the built-in options, which are either based on tags in the current buffer or global tags -- there is completion based on those tags, and speed commands for tags with shortcuts already assigned:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Setting-tags.html#Setting-tags  There is no built-in function that specifically suggests tags based on the current headline.  What you seek is certainly possible, but someone would need to write a custom solution.

Comment: I am relatively new to emacs and org mode, but have spent quite a bit of time searching the web for a solution, so I didn't really expect the solution to be "built in".  I was hoping that someone had seen or written some coding to do this.  It looks like Erik has done that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function gets the headline of the entry the point is one, splits it into words and adds as a tag any word it finds in either `org-tag-alist` or `org-tag-persistent-alist`

```
(defun org-auto-tag ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((alltags (append org-tag-persistent-alist org-tag-alist))
        (headline-words (split-string (org-get-heading t t)))
        )
    (mapcar (lambda (word) (if (assoc word alltags)
                             (org-toggle-tag word 'on)))
            headline-words))
    )
```

It might be useful to add a function like this to `org-capture-before-finalize-hook` to automatically tag newly captured entries.

Comment: Thanks Erik!  I'll try this out in the next day or two and see how it works.

Comment: I can confirm this works, but only if capitalisation of words and tags is identical. All my tags are in upper case, so adding function `upcase` around `org-get-heading` was necessary.

Comment: So `org-capture-before-finalize-hook` is the one to use instead of `org-capture-after-finalize-hook`? I found the naming a bit confusing. I sounds like that tagging operation is performed "after" the capturing is done.

Comment: The only difference between the "before" and "after" hooks is whether the capture buffer is still current when it runs.  Stuff like tagging can be done in either.